# Visual Basic FolderBrowser returning no value

Tags: vb.net

I was looking to memorizing a folder path to my.settings indefinitely.
I tried

```
Private Sub CartellaTessutiToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CartellaTessutiToolStripMenuItem.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub FolderBrowserDialog1_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FolderBrowserDialog1.Disposed
        My.Settings.CartellaTex = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        My.Settings.Save()
        MsgBox(My.Settings.CartellaTex.ToString)
    End Sub
```

My.settings.CartellaTex setting is set to String.

I am sure no value is returned as by setting up a msg box at the end of the text such message does not show.
All the functions in my app that rely on My.settings.CartellaTex go in error.

I have read somewhere that FolderBrowser struggles when something called "threads" are involved, but this code ran perfectly yesterday night. Keep in mind I am using Visual Studio on Parallels for Mac but again this used to work hours ago. I am really new to vb.net and this is as much knowledge I have. Please be patient.

Comment: Get rid of `FolderBrowserDialog1_Disposed` event and insert its code after `FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: You know what the modal dialog is and when the code following is executed. No? Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) section of the `ShowDialog` method doc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CartellaTessutiToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CartellaTessutiToolStripMenuItem.Click
  If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = DailogResult.OK Then
      My.Settings.CartellaTex = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
      My.Settings.Save()
      MsgBox(My.Settings.CartellaTex.ToString)
  End If
End Sub
```